# Программное осветление экрана

Tags: linux

В солнечные дни неудобно работать за ноутбуком, даже при установке яркости экрана в максимальное значение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно программно «осветлить» всё изображение на экране (может это умеют делать команды xterm/xrandr, или существуют специальные программы для этого)?

Под осветлением я понимаю что-то вроде [этого](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/) (поканальное (r/g/b) вычитание некоторого значения).

Comment: `xrandr --output <OUT> --gamma 1:2:3` — не оно? Да, по идее оно должно быть не программное, а аппаратное на уровне видеокарты...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, скорее всего да, завтра попробую, спасибо!

Comment: ещё `--brightness 1.5` в ту же степь, чтобы менять все три параметра одновременно (я не уверен как именно они взаимодействуют)... в большинстве DE также есть свои крутилки гаммы...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, я попробовал, отлично работает, огромное спасибо! В моей DE (KDE) тоже есть настройки для этого, но думаю что командой удобнее, так как можно написать скрипт и на хоткей повешать. Ещё раз спасибо!